# frequent GET requests stop being actually processed by HTTP handler / aways return same value

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

I have inherited this code which runs a 1-second-JQuery-Ajax-loop on the client side. It used to heavily exploit cookies and I am trying to change it to plain stateless HTTP at least, but now I have the following problem:

Every POST from the client is processed, and the first few GETs too, but after a short while the server-side `HttpHandler` is not even called on GET requests and the client code success callbacks always get passed the same - non-updated - data.

**//edit:** since people tend to assume otherwise: I have stepped through the code with a debugger, so when I say "handler is not called on get requests" and "client code success callbacks get passed the same data always" I mean that quite literally.

I figure this might be a problem of the Web Server caching responses to HTTP requests, but it's kind of a wild guess.

So I have a bunch of questions which might help me solve such problems in the future:

- Is this a reasonable theory?
- I would like to somehow have an overview over all the HTTP requests
  the server registers and how he chooses to process them.
- Also, where and how would I go about configuring the server beyond
  the `web.config`, if for example I wanted to configure its caching
  behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the clientside cache which is causing this.
Set `cache` to `false` on your AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://your.url.here",
    cache: false
})
.done(function(data) {
    // ...    
});
```

More details [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Hah, funny ...
I disabled server-side caching and it solved the problem.
I tried disabling client-side first, but I kind of remember a different syntax, so maybe that was just off. Will see when I'm back at work. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: Might be a good idea to include some details about how the serverside caching has been set up; if an expires httpheader gets set, then the client makes no new request until after that expiration datetime and reuses the data given by the first request.

Comment: Oh well, I am - as you might have gathered - quite the noob with anything .NET-related.
So I don't really know how  to gather information on server configuration - as far as I can tell there is little to no programmatic configuration, and the web.config has no caching-related entires (and little overall). 
I also don't really know any tools but netsh yet that might be of any help.
I know I have quite some general reading to do, but perhaps you could give me some hints up front.
Best wishes.

Comment: No prob, you are showing effort! For this kind of issues, have a look at [Fiddler](http://getfiddler.com); it's an http-debugger, showing which http-requests get made and for each one its request and response details, including http-headers. Pay attention to the Cache-Control and Expires response http-headers.